# What is the install terminal and how to remove it from VS Code terminal window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access, vscode-remote

This started showing up a few months back in my VS Code setup. It wasn't bothering so much, so I kept ignoring it. I am not sure what it's called, but searching around with "install window" or other combinations for VS Code gives some unexpected results. I am using remote-ssh extension for development and believe that it has something to do with a remote extension setting. If I try to close this window, my ssh connection breaks and VS Code opens up another of these to recreate the ssh connection.

[image: Install window]

I have tried checking and unchecking various remote-ssh extensions but to no avail. Even reinstalling VS Code didn't do any good. I don't see the same behavior on other machines that I have VS Code installed.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me get rid of this terminal. My VS Code is running on macos and ssh server is Ubuntu if this helps.

Comment: It is very annoying.  I don't want to see all that junk.  Couldn't it just show some kind of status in the bottom bar?  Also, it has gotten worse in latest version.  You can't even kill the window anymore.  It just comes back, cluttering up my terminal list.  BTW, how should I create an issue for this in github?  It isn't a bug or feature request.

Comment: I went to github but it sent me here to ask this question. I was hoping some VS Code maintainer would read this and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `"remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true` from your User settings JSON file, then exit VSCode and re-launch the workspace. If that doesn't work set the setting to `false` instead.

Comment: OMG! You are an angel! Thanks, I have gone through some many of the remote ssh settings but nothing had worked! That was such an eyesore for last one year for me!